# How I can validate Listbox (Select) - Headless UI with Formik + Yup?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup, headless-ui

I am working with Listbox (Select) - Headless UI with Formik, how I can validate this dropdown with  Formik and Yup?

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-dream-irfj3e?file=/src/App.js

I would like you to show on the code which I fixed above, one of options of validation of this component.

Code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Listbox } from "@headlessui/react";

const people = [
  { id: 1, name: "Durward Reynolds", unavailable: false },
  { id: 2, name: "Kenton Towne", unavailable: false },
  { id: 3, name: "Therese Wunsch", unavailable: false },
  { id: 4, name: "Benedict Kessler", unavailable: true },
  { id: 5, name: "Katelyn Rohan", unavailable: false }
];

const MyListbox = ({ defaultValue }) => {
  const [selectedPerson, setSelectedPerson] = useState({
    id: -1,
    name: defaultValue,
    unavailable: false
  });

  return (
    <Listbox value={selectedPerson} onChange={setSelectedPerson}>
      <Listbox.Button>{selectedPerson.name}</Listbox.Button>
      <Listbox.Options>
        {people.map((person) => (
          <Listbox.Option
            key={person.id}
            value={person}
            disabled={person.unavailable}
          >
            {person.name}
          </Listbox.Option>
        ))}
      </Listbox.Options>
    </Listbox>
  );
};

export default MyListbox;
```

Comment: Just wanted to know if you were able to find a solution. Even I am trying to add Validation to ListBox in the Vue 3 or Nuxt 3 application. Please provide some references if you have.